# Creating Polygon Wallet with Python

Tags: python, blockchain

How can i create polygon (matic) wallet with Python I saw that we can use Web.py for this purpose but It creates ethereum wallet also I couldnt find enough information for creating wallets most of them were javascript based
I will display the wallet in Flask server with User auth system I’ve built Will store the details for wallets in sql database.

I tried web3.py which created ethereum wallet for me, but is that ethereum wallet is usable with polygon chain?

Answer (score 1):

Polygon is a layer 2 Ethereum chain, so it is supposed to be fully compatible with Ethereum. According to Polygon's docs, you should configure the Web3 RPC-URL to https://rpc-mumbai.matic.today for the testnet, and https://polygon-rpc.com/ for the mainnet.